# How do I protect only part of a Mediawiki article from editing?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm building a Mediawiki site which will include a few thousand Bot-generated articles.  I want users to be able to edit lower sections of each article, but not edit the bot-generated sections.

I found an abandoned extension called [ProtectSection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ProtectSection) which did this, but I don't have the skills to update it to work with the current Mediawiki release.

I'm considering making the Bot-generated articles protected, and then transcluding them into user-editable articles.  If I do that, can I hide the original Bot-generated articles from search engines, and from being navigable within the wiki?

Also, I'd like users to be able to reference prior versions of the bot-generated articles, as their text will be updated from time to time by the bot.  If I transclude and hide the bot-generated articles, I'm assuming their history then will be inaccessible.  This wouldn't be a problem if I could keep the bot-generated articles available, with user-editable sections in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a bad news. It's really difficult to make part of article protected. Current mediawiki architecture doesn't allow it from scratch.

What I suggest you to do is create [custom namespase](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces) and place all bot's articles there.

> ```
> // Define constants for my additional namespaces.
> define("NS_FOO", 3000); // This MUST be even.
> define("NS_FOO_TALK", 3001); // This MUST be the following odd integer.
>
> // Add namespaces.
> $wgExtraNamespaces[NS_FOO] = "Foo";
> $wgExtraNamespaces[NS_FOO_TALK] = "Foo_talk"; // Note underscores in the namespace name.
> ```

Resrict ordinary users edit this custom namespace, [here is some info](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_editing_of_an_entire_namespace). But allow users to watch history of this pages.

> ```
> # Only allow autoconfirmed users to edit Project namespace
> $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_PROJECT] = array( 'autoconfirmed' );
>
> # Don't allow anyone to edit non-talk pages until they've confirmed their
> # e-mail address (assuming we have no custom namespaces and allow edits
> # from non-emailconfirmed users to start with)
> # Note for 1.13: emailconfirmed group and right were removed from default
> # setup, if you want to use it, you'll have to re-enable it manually
> $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_MAIN]     = $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_USER]  =
> $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_PROJECT]  = $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_IMAGE] =
> $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_TEMPLATE] = $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_HELP]  =
> $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_CATEGORY] = array( 'emailconfirmed' );
>
> # Only allow sysops to edit "Policy" namespace
> $wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['editpolicy'] = true;
> $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_POLICY] = array( 'editpolicy' );
> ```

Last step you already know - use [Tranclution](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion).